How to configure JWT to work with cookies?
I have a Django application that functions as an API. Currently, it can generate access and refresh JWT tokens and save these tokens as cookies. My problem arises when verifying these tokens in other endpoints. Even though they are being sent correctly, authentication fails. It would be too much information to explain here, but I customized the user class and configured it to use JWT. I appreciate any help, as I'm not sure what to do. When I try to access an endpoint that requires authentication with a token, I receive the message 'Authentication credentials were not provided' and get a 401 error in the response. I believe it could be an issue with the parent class, maybe a method that wasn't overridden but should have been. Here's the repository of the project, which is a small-scale study/test project: https://github.com/MasterTJ123/servant_rpg_back

Please [edit] your question and share a [mre] in the question body itself. Links to external sites with your code aren't sufficient to count as a [mre] and debugging posts lacking one would be closed for lacking debugging details.

In your settings, you've sepecified the AUTH_USER_MODEL like below
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'servant_rpg_back.Usuario'

But your auth model is in  'servant_rpg_back.app.Usuario'
That causes an issue since the system does not know which exact model to use for authentication.
Maybe you should add this AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'servant_rpg_back.aoo.Usuario'
or this AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.Usuario' to your settings.
